# Numpy: get the higest L value

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I read a picture and transform it to LAB model as follows:

```
import cv2
imbgr=cv2.imread('rgb.pic')
imlab=cv2.cvtColor(imbgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

Now, I want to get the highest (max) value of `L` (if there are lot of occurences of the same value, I want to get only one occurence of it).

I know I need to use somehow [numpy.amax()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) but I have no idead how to use it here. Any hints ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull each of the `L`, `a` and `b` arrays using this:

```
L,a,b=imlab[:,:,0], imlab[:,:,1], imlab[:,:,2]
```

Then use `np.amax()` to find it